# TYPO3 delete reference files with object

Tags: typo3

I have TYPO3 version 7.6.18. Tell me please how make auto deleting all reference files when I repository->remove($object)  ?

Comment: which repository? which files - file references, or the files itself?

Comment: not important which repository. My own model. Yes file references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `@cascade remove` to your domain model property's docblock to have it removed on removal of the entity.

Here's a snippet of the [`blog_example` extension](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/eb049dba4d3d4f0ff7cbc60b60eae17b66793626/typo3/sysext/extbase/Tests/Functional/Fixtures/Extensions/blog_example/Classes/Domain/Model/Blog.php#L50) used in Extbase's functional tests:

```
/**
 * The posts of this blog
 *
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\ExtbaseTeam\BlogExample\Domain\Model\Post>
 * @lazy
 * @cascade remove
 */
protected $posts = null;
```